# start of making a mailing list and saving it to notepad (perfectiblely in html)

Tags: html, email, comments

Hey I'm making a mailing list and I am wondering how do i set up a way for people to send me a message of their email and for it to automatically save to a notepad file or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Really depends on the scale of email list 10s,100s,10000s and the $ budget. There is loads of pre-cooked software for email management/handling from listserv to mailchimp. On the smallest scale some email clients outlook/thunderbird can be set to perform actions on incoming email from/to target address such as put in folder or forward.

Best approach depends on your environment (mac/linux/pc) and email infrastructure on premise, in cloud etc. and ability to code

see https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.parser.html